# Draw label with Custom Font

Tags: iphone

I want to draw a Label with Origram font . But there are some problem in folding the text at edges of the letter. Can any one one help me for this.

I have attached the image. My label will look like this image. This is image for the drawing text.

[image]

Comment: where is the image? show us what you have tried. Thank you!

Comment: do you have .ttf font file for this Origram font?

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Download origram font file from http://www.fonts2u.com/origram.font site
Step 2: Add font file to your project
Step 3: Register your font with application, Refere following screenshot for it.
[image: Refer this screenshot to configure external font file with your application]
Step 4: Create a lable and set your font using following code

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100)];
[lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Origram" size:30.0f]];
[lbl setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[lbl setText:@"Origram Font Test"];
[self.view addSubview:lbl];
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping me.I am able to add font but folding on the font edge are not displaying. My exact problem is that(Folding the text style).Can you please help me?

Comment: you can not display folding edges with TTF for that you need to use image that you have and then make customize stuffs.

Comment: Thank a lot . Can you please help me for for using image.Because I am totally get frustrated.

Comment: Have you a sample for this ? . Thanks dude again and again.

Comment: read [this](http://www.71squared.com/en/article/851/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-4-bitmap-font-class) article about bitmap font in cocos2D

Comment: Hi Friend, Can you share your email Id. I want to add you. ACtually we have to show demo for above image with in 3 hours. Thats why I am so upset for this font.

Comment: Hi, How to create its .fnt file for  above image.

Comment: Can You please help me to create the .fnt file from png ?

Comment: there are lots of tools available to create bmp file for font. search on google friend refer [this](http://www.bmglyph.com) and also refer [this](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/release_notes:0_8#bitmap_fonts)

Comment: Hi friend, I am getting link fo r(Convert .fnt from .ttf ). But I am not able to search the link for (Convert .fnt from .png).

Comment: straight away its not available ,you need to designer support for it [try this](http://www.sovapps.com/localize-your-game-with-bitmap-fonts-and-cocos2d/)

Comment: Thank you very much friend. I am still not able to do this lets try it in the morning.Thanks again and again. Actually I am new in cocoas2d. I am looking forward for your help.

Comment: Application is crashed when we using the "http://www.71squared.com/en/article/851/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-4-bitmap-font-class" link for same

Comment: here is the famous tutorial for font drawing in cocos2d, chipmunk, read the article in the intial section you will find it describes about [font from image](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3128/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-game-with-chipmunk-physics-tutorial), read the tutorial carefully and follow the steps, and you need cocos2d to be installed in your mac

Comment: Hi friend , I want to change the frame of the CCLabel but it is not setting the frame. Any !dea ..?

Comment: you can search over internet for that, or go through this [Documentation for COCOS2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:labels)

Comment: Hi Friend, My client is not able to match the .fnt and .png file. So I decided that I create .fnt and .png by myself. So there are any free software for create .png and .fnt?. Thanks in advanced...